# Next Closest Number in Array

Tags: java

I need help finding the next closest number in an array, starting with the first position and continuing until the end of the array. I am looking for the greatest number, closest to the target number. The highest number should return Integer.MAX_VALUE.

For example:

```
int[] numbers = {12, 42, 13, 56, 41, 50, 100, 60};
```

would return

```
12 : 13
42 : 50
13 : 41
56 : 60
41 : 42
50 : 56 
100 : MAX_VALUE
60 : 100
```

I was successful writing nested for loops which returned the next greatest number but cannot for the life of me figure out how to return the next greatest number that is closest to the target number.

```
int next = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

  for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {

        if (numbers[i] < numbers [j]) {
          next = numbers[j];
          break;
        }
  }
  System.out.println(numbers[i] + ":" + next);
}
```

Comment: No one is safe...

Comment: If you were successful writing some code, why not show what you have, and explain in more detail what you're lacking with that code? --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the tip

Comment: I think you got result wrong, because my code returns `{12=13, 42=50, 13=41, 56=60, 41=42, 50=56, 100=2147483647, 60=100}`. You're missing the `13 : 41` mapping, and your mapping of `50 : 60` should be `50 : 56`

Comment: whoops... thank you

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method would be to sort the array using [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) method. Then for each element you just select the next one (MAX_VALUE for the last element).

If you have to do it using loops, for each element find the min element in the array that is bigger than current element.

```
for (int e0 : x) {
    int eMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int e1 : x) {
        if (e1 > e0 && e1 < eMin) {
            eMin = e1;
        }
    }
    if (eMin == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        System.out.println(e0 + " : MAX_VALUE");
    } else {
        System.out.println(e0 + " : " + eMin);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help! I was able to complete this using Arrays.sort.

Answer (score 0):

Take one more temp array and copy x in to temp & sort temp and iterate x and keeo counter on temp display next closest number from temp.